# Skipping promise chain after handling error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Using the https://github.com/kriskowal/q library, I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
// Module A

function moduleA_exportedFunction() {
  return promiseReturningService().then(function(serviceResults) {
    if (serviceResults.areGood) {
      // We can continue with the rest of the promise chain
    }
    else {
      performVerySpecificErrorHandling();
      // We want to skip the rest of the promise chain
    }
  });
}

// Module B

moduleA_exportedFunction()
  .then(moduleB_function)
  .then(moduleB_anotherFunction)
  .fail(function(reason) {
    // Handle the reason in a general way which is ok for module B functions
  })
  .done()
;
```

Basically if the service results are bad, I'd like to handle the failure in module A, using logic that is specific to the internals of module A, but still skip the remaining module B functions in the promise chain.

The obvious solution for skipping module B functions is to throw an error/reason from module A. However, then I would need to handle that in module B. And ideally I'd like to do it without needing any extra code in module B for that.

Which may very well be impossible :) Or against some design principles of Q.

In which case, what kind of alternatives would you suggest?

I have two approaches in mind, but both have their disadvantages:

1. Throw a specific error from module A and add specific handling code to module B:

   ```
   .fail(function(reason) {
     if (reason is specificError) {
       performVerySpecificErrorHandling();
     }
     else {
       // Handle the reason in a general way which is ok for module B functions
     }
   })
   ```
2. Perform the custom error handling in module A, then after handling the error, throw a fake rejection reason. In module B, add a condition to ignore the fake reason:

   ```
   .fail(function(reason) {
     if (reason is fakeReason) {
       // Skip handling
     }
     else {
       // Handle the reason in a general way which is ok for module B functions
     }
   })
   ```

Solution 1 requires adding module A specific code to module B.

Solution 2 solves this, but the whole fake rejection approach seems very hackish.

Can you recommend other solutions?

Comment: Let's play a little game - write how you would accomplish this in synchronous code if there were no promises involved at all?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion :D I realised that in synchronous code I would probably return a 'shouldContinue' boolean from the module A function and handle that in module B. In promise-based code it looked like a hack, but in hindsight it's far less hacky than the fake errors and whatnot :)

Comment: Don't forget to utilize `.spread` for returning an array and looking at its arguments as parameters to be able to react to more than one variable: `Q([false,{}]).spread(function(success,data){ /* code here */})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Benjamin Gruenbaum's comments and answer - if I was writing this in synchronous code, I would make `moduleA_exportedFunction` return a `shouldContinue` boolean.

So with promises, it would basically be something like this (disclaimer: this is psuedo-code-ish and untested)

```
// Module A

function moduleA_exportedFunction() {
  return promiseReturningService().then(function(serviceResults) {
    if (serviceResults.areGood) {
      // We can continue with the rest of the promise chain
      return true;
    }
    else {
      performVerySpecificErrorHandling();
      // We want to skip the rest of the promise chain
      return false;
    }
  });
}

// Module B

moduleA_exportedFunction()
  .then(function(shouldContinue) {
    if (shouldContinue) {
      return moduleB_promiseReturningFunction().then(moduleB_anotherFunction);
    }
  })
  .fail(function(reason) {
    // Handle the reason in a general way which is ok for module B functions
    // (And anything unhandled from module A would still get caught here)
  })
  .done()
;
```

It does require some handling code in module B, but the logic is neither specific to module A's internals nor does it involve throwing and ignoring fake errors - mission accomplished! :)

Comment: For the record - newer promise libraries do not require you to call `.done` explicitly but will instead track unhandled rejections for you. Q had experimental support for this at a point but they're still working on it - I think you should definitely consider a library that helps you with this :)

Answer (score 16):

### Let's talk about control constructs.

In JavaScript, code flows in two ways when you call a function.

- It can `return` a value to the caller, indicating that it completed successfully.
- It can `throw` an error to the caller, indicating that an exceptional operation occurred.

It looks something like:

```
function doSomething(){ // every function ever
  if(somethingBad) throw new Error("Error operating");
  return value; // successful completion.
}

try{
  doSomething();
  console.log("Success");
} catch (e){
  console.log("Boo");
}
```

Promises model this exact same behavior.

In Promises, code flows in exactly two ways when you call a function in a `.then` handler:

- It can `return` a promise or a value which indicates that it completed successfully.
- It can `throw` an error which indicates that an exceptional state occured.

It looks something like:

```
var doSomething = Promise.method(function(){
  if(somethingBad) throw new Error("Error operating");
  return someEventualValue(); // a direct value works here too
}); // See note, in Q you'd return Q.reject()

Promise.try(function(){ // in Q that's Q().then
  doSomething();
  console.log("Success");
}).catch(function(e){
  console.log("Boo");
});
```

#### Promises model flow of control itself

A promise is an abstraction over the notion *sequencing operations* itself. It describes how control passes from one statement from another. You can consider `.then` an abstraction over a semicolon.

### Let's talk about synchronous code

Let's see how synchronous code would look in your case.

```
function moduleA_exportedFunction() {
  var serviceResults = someSynchronousFunction();
    if (serviceResults.areGood) {
      // We can continue with the rest of our code
    }
    else {
      performVerySpecificErrorHandling();
      // We want to skip the rest of the chain
    }
}
```

So, how continuing with the rest of our code is simply `returning`. This is the same in synchronous code and in asynchronous code with promises. Performing very specific error handling is also ok.

How would we skip the rest of the code in the synchronous version?

```
doA();
doB();
doC(); // make doD never execute and not throw an exception
doD();
```

Well, even if not immediately, there *is* a rather simple way to make doD never execute by causing doC to enter into an infinite loop:

```
function doC() {
    if (!results.areGood) {
      while(true){} // an infinite loop is the synchronous analogy of not continuing
                    // a promise chain.
    }
}
```

So, it *is* possible to never resolve a promise - like the other answer suggests - return a pending promise. However, that is extremely poor flow control since the intent is poorly conveyed to the consumer and it will be likely very hard to debug. Imagine the following API:

> **moduleA_exportedFunction** - this function makes an API request and returns the service as a `ServiceData` object if the data is available. Otherwise, it *enters the program into an endless loop*.

A bit confusing, isn't it :)? However, it actually exists in some places. It's not uncommon to find the following in really old APIs.

> **some_bad_c_api()** - this function foos a bar, on failure it *terminates the process*.

So, what bothers us about terminating the process in that API anyway?

#### It's all about responsibility.

- It's the responsibility of the called API to convey whether the API request was successful.
- It is the responsibility of the caller to decide what to do in each case.

In your case. ModelA is simply breaching the limit of its responsibility, it should not be *entitled* to make such decisions about the flow of the program. Whoever consumes it should make these decisions.

### Throw

The better solution is to throw an error and let the consumer handle it. I'll use [Bluebird promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) here since they're not only two orders of magnitude faster and have a much more modern API - they also have much *much* better debugging facilities - in this case - sugar for conditional catches and better stack traces:

```
moduleA_exportedFunction().then(function(result){
   // this will only be reached if no error occured
   return someOtherApiCall();
}).then(function(result2){
   // this will be called if the above function returned a value that is not a 
   // rejected promise, you can keep processing here
}).catch(ApiError,function(e){
   // an error that is instanceof ApiError will reach here, you can handler all API
   // errors from the above `then`s in here. Subclass errors
}).catch(NetworkError,function(e){
   // here, let's handle network errors and not `ApiError`s, since we want to handle
   // those differently
}).then(function(){
   // here we recovered, code that went into an ApiError or NetworkError (assuming
   // those catch handlers did not throw) will reach this point.
   // Other errors will _still_ not run, we recovered successfully
}).then(function(){
   throw new Error(); // unless we explicitly add a `.catch` with no type or with 
                      // an `Error` type, no code in this chain will run anyway.
});
```

So in a line - you would do what you would do in synchronous code, as is usually the case with promises.

<sup>Note Promise.method is just a convenience function Bluebird has for wrapping functions, I just hate synchronous throwing in promise returning APIs as it creates major breakage.</sup>

Comment: Nice extra elaboration! I think the synchronous example could benefit from including a try/catch though. I had no idea Bluebird had that functionality for catching errors by type, awesome!

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration! I particularly loved the infinite loop analogy - I knew there was something off about the idea of an unresolved promise but couldn't put my finger on it until now. As for marking an answer, however, I'm considering posting a new one myself that specifically uses a returned boolean from module A. However, I intend to give due credit to your comment and response for inspiring the solution :)

Comment: David - good Idea I've expanded on that. @mjomble please do feel free to add your own answer and accept whichever answer reflects how you solved your problem best. I'd rather see three solutions to the same problem than the same exact solution to three problems :) Returning a boolean is a perfectly valid strategy and is useful in the cases where APIs not succeeding is not an exceptional use case.

Comment: TL;DR: `throw new Error(message)` from your first error handler function.

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of a design thing. In general, when a module or service returns a promise, you want it to resolve if the call was successful, and to fail otherwise. Having the promise neither resolve or fail, even though you know the call was unsuccessful, is basically a silent failure.

But hey, I don't know the specifics of your modules, or reasons, so if you do want to fail silently in this case, you can do it by returning an unresolved promise:

// Module A

```
function moduleA_exportedFunction() {
  return promiseReturningService().then(function(serviceResults) {
    if (serviceResults.areGood) {
      // We can continue with the rest of the promise chain
    }
    else {
      performVerySpecificErrorHandling();
      // We want to skip the rest of the promise chain
      return q.defer().promise;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: +1 for a solution and for calling it a silent failure - which it is. I've added an answer that goes into more detail into the abstractions but I definitely like this one too.