# Promise: skip all fulfill and reject reactions but execute .finally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I have function called `request`:

```js
function request (endpoint) {
  return axios.request(endpoint).then(api.onSuccess).catch(api.onError)
}
```

`api.onSuccess`:

```js
  onSuccess (response) {
    let breakChain = false
    ... some logic goes here ...
    return breakChain ? (new Promise(() => {})) : response
  }
```

`api.onError`:

```js
  onError (error) {
    let breakChain = false
    ... some logic goes here ...
    if (breakChain) {
      return new Promise(() => {})
    } else {
      throw error
    }
  }
```

`api` holds a lot of functions that represent different API calls based on provided endpoints data and return `request(endpoint)`.

Currenly I have code, as you can see, that return Promise with empty executor that is always in pending state to stop the chain of subsequent `.then(...)` and `.catch(...)` handlers from execution as they just infinitely wait for that Promise to settle. This is done to handle certain API responses that have common response handling (like responses with code >= 500).
The problem is that now I need a call to `.finally()` (like in Vue cookbook - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html#Dealing-with-Errors) to restore some component's state nevertheless of whether there is an error or not, but this approach of pending Promise is an obstacle.

The question is: is it possible to skip all subsequent `.then(...)` and `.catch(...)` calls within one of such handlers to go directly to `.finally()`?

Update. I haven't mentioned the important bit - `api.onSuccess` and `api.onError` are **basic** handlers. In another application components there are additional handlers appended to the end of that basic chain presented in `request` function. Usual chain of some API call has a  following resulting form:

```js
return axios.request(endpoint).then(api.onSuccess).catch(api.onError).then((response) => {...}).catch(() => {...}).finally(() => {...})
```

(sometimes there is no `.finally()` or `.catch(...)` block)

Comment: What purpose do `api.onSuccess` and `api.onError` serve? From here it looks like all they do is make it difficult to use `request` properly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder they are initial handlers - i.e. `api.onError` checks whether response has code >= 500 and if it does, set `breakChain` flag to `true` as this scenario (code >= 500) has common handling across the application

Comment: @RomanYakubovich you can always write your own `Promise`-like and implement all the fancy things. (Not even need to compliant with standard.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to skip all subsequent `.then(...)` and `.catch(...)` calls within one of such handlers to go directly to `.finally()`?

[No.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24355960/1048572)

> Currenly I stop the chain by just infinitely waiting - yet this approach of pending Promise is an obstacle.

Indeed, don't do that. You can skip `then` handlers by [using rejections (exceptions) for flow control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20714460/1048572), but the more appropriate way is to handle this by nesting the part of the chain to be skipped [inside an `if` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21576862/1048572).

> This is done to handle certain API responses that have common response handling (like responses with code >= 500)

For that, you should use something like

```
return axios.request(endpoint).then(response => {
    …
}).catch(error => {
    if (api.handleCommonError(error)) return; // returns false if it couldn't handle the error
    …
}).finally(() => {
    …
});
```

Yes, you cannot hide this kind of error handling inside an `api.request` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). All modern browsers support them, and your bundler can make them compatible with older browsers.

For example:

```
async function request (endpoint) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.request(endpoint);
    return api.onSuccess(response);
  } catch (err) {
    api.onError(err);
  } finally {
    // Always executed, even if no error was thrown
  }
}
```

You can also do it more traditionally:

```
function request (endpoint) {
  return axios.request(endpoint).then(api.onSuccess, api.onError).then(() => {
    // Code is always executed after error / success
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I can't use this way. Please look at the question update (sorry not to include that initially)

Comment: No, `async`/`await` doesn't help here. The `finally` block still doesn't run if an `await`ed promise never resolves.

Comment: If an awaited promise doesn't resolve nothing helps, neither the `then` nor the `catch` would happen. Using `async` / `await` at least lets you branch off and do conditional logic far more easily than with promises.